# Bootstrap: center <h3> underneath table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[**Link**](https://gyazo.com/1ee97efa7e65a97b98434911da946cd3)

Heres the website containing the full html rendered [**Link**](http://rustmarketexchange.meteor.com/sell)

Here's my **code**:

```
<template name="activeOrderTable"><table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Commodity</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price (High Quality Metal)</th>
        <th>Order Type</th>
        <th>Merchant</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date Added</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each activeOrders}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{prettifyCommodity commodity}}</td>
            <td>{{quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{price}}</td>
            <td>{{prettifyOrderType orderType}}</td>
            <td>{{merchant}}</td>
            <td>{{location}}</td>
            <td>{{prettifyDate createdAt}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-id="{{_id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
    {{else}}
        <h3>You have no active orders</h3>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to center the `You have no active orders`

I've tried class `text-center` but its not working.

Comment: Have you tried giving your H3 a 100% width with css (also adding the text-center)?

Comment: @IndieRok Yes, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Is there anyway you can add conditional CSS to only else part? It is a easy CSS hack if it is possible.

Comment: it seems like you are rendering a `h3` inside a `tbody` which is invalid HTML. Move the `h3` outside the table, or wrap it in `<tr><td colspan=x>h3 goes here</td></tr>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `H3` element is inside the table so the browser is trying to 'fix it'.
You should wrap your H3 tag in `<tr><td colspan="6"><td></tr>` tags and then apply `class="text-center"` to `H3`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `text-center` class on your `h3` tag directly, not on it's parent divs like this:

```
{{else}}
    <h3 class="text-center">You have no active orders</h3>
{{/each}}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/26/

Comment: This didn't work for me. Since it's part of a larger template I will add the other code that may be affecting it.

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle Paul.

Comment: Can you give me a link to a live site with the above codes as the code I gave above should work beautifully if your site is built on bootstrap.

Comment: Give me a moment to deploy it then I will link it for you Andrew.

Comment: No worries Andrew. Thank you for looking at it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must try applying vanilla CSS to the above code.

```css
table.table h3 {
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that already and I tried your CSS. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @paul try the above property and your alignment would work fine